# SEO Friendly URL output Un-Styled HTML page with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my URL re-writes. The link works, but output's plain un-styled HTML. Not seen this before, or i am overlooking something very simple so any help would be greatfully received.

This is my .htacess re-write

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) gallery.php?id=$1
```

This is my php function

```
function url_slug($string, $space = '-') {
    $string = str_replace('&', 'and', $string);

    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]/', '', $string);

    $string = strtolower($string);

    $string = preg_replace('/[ ]+/', ' ', $string);

    $string = str_replace(' ', $space, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

This is my index page with the gallery section

```
<?php
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 6');

foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 port-item">

    <div class="port-mask">

    <?php
    $id     = escape($row->id);
    $title  = escape($row->url);
    $string = url_slug($title);

    echo '<a href="gallery/' . $id . '/' . $string . '"><h3>' . escape($row->section_title) . '</h3></a>';

    ?>

    <div class="port-line clearfix"></div>

        <p><?php echo escape($row->section_category) ?></p>

        <?php
        echo '<a href="gallery/' . $id . '/' . $string . '"><i class="viewbtn fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>';

        ?>

        <a href="images/gallery/<?php echo escape($row->section_image) ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="viewimg fa fa-search"></i></a>

        </div>

        <img src="images/gallery/<?php echo escape($row->section_image) ?>" alt="<?php echo escape($row->alt) ?>">

</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

This is my gallery.php from the link above

```
<?php
$sql = DB::getInstance()->get('gallery', array('id', '=', Input::get('id')));

foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
?>

    <section class="top-content clearfix">

        <div class="clearfix big-box para-opacity" data-auto-play="9000" data-stellar-ratio="0.4" data-stellar-position-property="position">

            <div class="box-title">
                <p><?php echo escape($row->gallery_slider_p) ?></p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h3><?php echo escape($row->gallery_slider_h3) ?></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="works-slider slider" data-auto-play="9000">
                <div class="slide img-bg clearfix" data-background="images/gallery/<?php echo escape($row->gallery_slider) ?>"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

<?php
}
?>
```

The URL link when clicked looks like this from index.php

```
http://localhost/projects/XXXPROJECTXXX/index
```

to the gallery.php

```
http://localhost/projects/XXXPROJECTXXX/gallery/1/chinese-contemporary-abstract-lady
```

So, what is wrong??  Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.htaccess create's problem with url,

what you can change all your urls of

> image
>
> js
>
> css

into absolute url, add your domain in them, this works for me.

Comment: Not sure why it creates a problem, though this seems to have worked. Never seen this before. But thanks :-)